# How to pass a class based task into CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat, class-based-tasks

As seen in the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html) class based tasks are a fair way to express complex logic.

However, the docs do not specify how to add your shiny newly created class based task into you `CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE` (using django)

Thing I tried:
`celery.py`

```
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS, 'task_summary')
@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    from payments.tasks.generic.payeer import PayeerPaymentChecker
    from payments.tasks.generic.ok_pay import OkPayPaymentChecker

    okpay_import = OkPayPaymentChecker()
    payeer_imprt = PayeerPaymentChecker()

    sender.add_periodic_task(60.0, okpay_import.s(),
                             name='OkPay import',
                             expires=30)

    sender.add_periodic_task(60.0, payeer_imprt.s(),
                             name='Payeer import',
                             expires=30)
```

-- OR --

`payments/task_summary.py`

```
from tasks.generic.import import OkPayPaymentChecker, PayeerPaymentChecker
 run_okpay = OkPayPaymentChecker()
 run_payeer = PayeerPaymentChecker()

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
# yes, i did try referring to the class here
'check_okpay_payments': {

    'task': 'payments.tasks.task_summary.run_okpay',
    'schedule': timedelta(seconds=60),
},
'check_payeer_payments': {
    'task': 'payments.task_summary.run_payeer',
    'schedule': timedelta(seconds=60),
},
}
```

Really don't know what to do, restoring to something like:
`payments/task_summary.py`

```
from payments.tasks.generic.ok_pay import OkPayPaymentChecker
from payments.tasks.generic.payeer import PayeerPaymentChecker
from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def run_payer():
    instance = PayeerPaymentChecker()
    return instance.run()


@shared_task
def run_okpay():
    instance = OkPayPaymentChecker()
    return instance.run()
```

Online Resources which I've checked and do not help me / solve the problem:

- https://denibertovic.com/posts/celery-best-practices/
- https://blog.balthazar-rouberol.com/celery-best-practices
- http://shulhi.com/class-based-celery-task/
- http://jsatt.com/blog/class-based-celery-tasks/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It took me a while to find the answer to this too, and because this question is so high up on google search results I figure I'd drop it here for people who are struggling to find the answer:

You add it just as you would a normal task but using the class name.

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'my_task_name': {
        'task': 'mymodule.tasks.MyTaskClass',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=60),
},
```

(This is assuming you have `mymodule/tasks.py` with:

```
from celery import Task

class MyTaskClass(Task):

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
       ... stuff ...
```

Comment: Although I have not implement your idea yet but up-vote for your intention

Comment: The structure is fine. But the class-based task doesn't work with Beat. I get a task discovery error.